# Noob Question: Symmetrized my bones, but Weight Painting is still mirrored?

Tags: weight-painting

So I am currently trying to weight paint the lips on my model such that they deform according to my Lip bones. I used Symmetrize to ensure that there are .L and .R groups, and the Mirror Modifier on my mesh has Vertex Groups checked. But when I go into Weight Paint mode and select one of these .L or .R bones, the weight painting is symmetrical. I would like it to be such that a bone on the right only influences vertices on the right. How may I go about achieving this?

[image: Weight painting is symmetrical]

Link to .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QuQFWPfEyLrBtm0oP8SSyCSxa-LeHZ24/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's because you still have a mirror modifier on your model. If you apply that you'll be able to weight paint just one side of your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh object does not have enough vertex groups for the deformed bone names.
The results of searching with the keyword "Lip" are shown in the Vertex Groups List in the figure.

Select Mesh Object, then Armature in Object Mode. Press the `Ctrl+P` key and select `With Empty Groups`.

[image]

PS: **Lip2C.L** is a non-deformed bone name and can be removed from the list.

Comment: Thank you tetii!